# How to get free-form linguistic input to act on a previous output?

Tags: free-form-input, natural-language

It [seems that Mathematica is capable of taking free-form input that acts on previous outputs](http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/11/16/programming-with-natural-language-is-actually-going-to-work/) (see "separate color channels"), but I'm having trouble getting it to work in my case.

I've got `=countries on the caspian sea` returning a useful list of countries, but when I say `=flags of those countries`, Mathematica seems to not understand that I'm referring back to the output of the previous step. Even if I had to say `=map over those` explicitly, I'd be happy to, but it doesn't seem to work.

So a few possible thoughts on what would help solve my problem:

- Are there any attempts anywhere at writing down the sorts of things that one should expect free-form input to support? I'm willing to learn how to speak its language if it'll help me help it help me.
- Does anyone have a successful example of `Map`ping over a list using free-form linguistic input?

Comment: May I add to your questions : has anyone managed to use free-form input on user defined variables and functions ? Something like `mylist={1, 2, 3}` and then `= average of mylist` ?

Answer (score 1):

**Note**

This answer assumes the most optimistic version of this question is "no, you cannot refer to the last output in words" and instead assumes you're happy using the `WolframAlpha` function.

**Answer**

In my experience = and == should not be expected to give reproducible output over a reasonable time period. It's better since V10 with the introduction of entities. If the output of a free-form input is a list of entities I'd expect something as follows to be relatively trustworthy:

[image]

Then I can use the output in the `WolframAlpha` function (note if I had M10.1 I would use `StringRiffle`):

```
WolframAlpha["flags of " <> Riffle[ToString /@ %, " "]]
```

The output is reasonable

[image]